# Can you add two address registers in 68000 using ADDA

Tags: 68000

For example if I write "ADDA A1, A5" would this be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. That's what the instruction is good for.

Note you must put the .l postfix after the instruction if you want a full 32-bit addition. Without the postfix, the assembler will assume word (16-bit) size and add the sign-extended word source operand to the destination.